# How to create table from join with a new unique primary key in SQL?

Tags: sql, join, teradata, outer-join

I'm trying to do a full-outer-join between two tables and adding a unique ID to the result in Teradata SQL.

```
Example:
__Table A__
id  col1
1   hi
2   hello

__Table B__
id  col1
1   hey
4   whatsup

_Table C (result full outer join)_
a_id  b_id  a_col1  b_col1
1     1     hi      hey
2     null  hello   null
null  4     null    whatsup
```

How do I add a unique primary key to Table C? I want something like the following:

```
_Table D (result full outer join with primary key "id")_
id    a_id  b_id  a_col1  b_col1
123   1     1     hi      hey
234   2     null  hello   null
567   null  4     null    whatsup
```

What I tried:

```
create table table_c as (
select
  a_id,
  b_id,
  a.col1 as a_col1,
  b.col1 as b_col1
from table_a as a
full outer join table b
  on a.id = b.id
)

with data primary key (a_id)
```

Problem with the above is that it expects 1 primary key to create the table, but neither a_id nor b_id are always unique in table_c.

Comment: Then you don't have a primary key.  The components of a primary key can be neither NULL nor duplicated.

Comment: Why do you say "add a unique primary key to Table C"? What are you actually trying to do? What do you want the DBMS to know? If  "neither a_id nor b_id are always unique in table_c" then you cannot want either column to be a PK/UNIQUE. Maybe you want (a_id, b_id) as PK. PS After you make this clear you are going to have an obvious faq.

Comment: Please always google error messages & many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using 1 variant search as title & keywords for tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. When you do have a non-duplicate code question to post please read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you really want is to combine the two ids into a single column:

```
create table table_c as
    select coalesce(a.id, b.id) as id
           a.col1 as a_col1,
           b.col1 as b_col1
    from table_a as a full outer join
         table b
          on a.id = b.id;
```

Assuming there are no duplicates and `id` is not `null` in either table, then this should work as the primary key.